# Bash losing string escapes when piping

Tags: bash, pipe, escaping

I have a program `a` that produces a stream of JSON documents where some of the fields contain strings with escaped double-quotes. This JSON is then piped into a Bash script `b` which invokes `jq` to do some filtering basically as follows:

```
while read j; do
  echo $j | jq 'select(.my_field | match("..."))' | ...
done
```

`jq` raises errors (e.g. "Invalid numeric literal") because it cannot parse those strings. This is because the escape `\` apparently gets lost between `a` and the invocation of `jq` in `b`: where `a` sees `"\""` (with escape), `b` sees only `"""` (without escape). Is there a way to preserve the escapes all the way into `jq` so that it can do its parsing? My current guess is that the culprit is one of the two pipes (`|`), but it could also be `read`.

Comment: You might need `read -r` to preserve backslashes without attempting to interpret them. In any case, you should quote `$j`.

Comment: Why are you using `while read` instead of just piping directly to `jq`?

Comment: @chepner your suggestion works for me. Thanks. If you want to turn the comment into an answer, I shall accept it.

Comment: @Barmar the `while read` is there because `a` produces a stream of JSON documents, and I want `b` to yield its output before `a` finishes. This was missing from my description: it's now updated.

Comment: @rookie099 `jq --stream` perhaps?

Comment: Stream mode is, unfortunately, rather difficult to use.

Comment: @chepner yes, I noticed so much meanwhile, and have already placed a [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77907536/non-trivial-example-with-jq-stream) with a concrete example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `read`  lets you use a backslash as a line-continuation operator:

```
$ read foo
x \
> y
$ declare -p foo
declare -- foo="x y"
```

(The documentation describes this as the backslash character escaping the next character, but I'm not aware of any other context where it matters.)

As such, it discards *any* backslash found in the input. Using `-r` disables this behavior, preserving any backslashes found in the input.

```
while read -r j; do
    echo "$j" | jq '...'
done
```

Comment: Some versions of `echo` (I think including bash's in some modes) will try to interpret backslashes in the string, leading to yet more weird results. So it would be safer to replace `echo "$j"` with `printf '%s\n' "$j"` (or use a `<<<"$j"` redirect instead of the pipe).

Comment: Yes, the POSIX standard says that `echo '\t`, for example, should output a tab character, not the digraph `\t`. `bash`'s default behavior diverges from the standard.