# Non-trivial example with jq --stream

Tags: streaming, jq

This is a follow-up to @kojiro's comment on my earlier question [*Bash losing string escapes when piping*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77902601/bash-losing-string-escapes-when-piping) that recommends `jq --stream`. My problem involves a stream of [Tetragon events](https://tetragon.io/docs/concepts/events/) that arrive in a JSON file. The structure is as follows:

```
...
{
  "process_exec": {
    "process": {
      "pid": ...,
      "uid": ...,
      "binary": "...",
      ...
    },
    "parent": {
      ...
    }
  },
  "time": "..."
}
{
  "process_exit": {
    "process": {
      ...
    },
    "parent": {
      ...
    }
  },
  "time": "..."
}
...
```

I would like to filter the stream such that only records of "type" `process_exit` remain. I have consulted the jq manual section on [*Streaming*](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#streaming) and a writeup [*Streaming With JQ*](https://www.reddit.com/r/bash/comments/myoft4/streaming_with_jq/), but to no avail so far. I have also tried the following expression and many similar variants: jq streaming [isn't easy to deal with](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#streaming) indeed. So how can I solve my particular problem? In summary: how can I employ `jq --streaming` in this case?

```
tail -f file | jq --stream \
  'fromstream(0 | truncate_stream(select(.[0][0] == "process_exit")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your input is a already stream of objects which you want to filter by the presence of a key. This can simply be done using `select` and `has` as follows:

```bash
jq 'select(has("process_exit"))'
```

If this should be a continuation of another filter (as suggested by your preceding question) which closed with a `select` by itself, simply use a pipe  to combine the two:

```bash
… | jq '… | select(… and has("process_exit"))'
```

---

If for some reason you need to generate the input with `--stream`, use `inputs` with the `-n` flag to capture and process the broken-down parts:

```
jq --stream -n 'fromstream(inputs) | select(has("process_exit"))'
```

Capturing on a deeper level (as with `truncate_stream` and then `select(.[0][0] …)`) doesn't make sense (here), as

- you'd miss the sibling nodes, and would only be able to reconstruct the object on that deeper level (i.e. only the parts below `.process_exit`), but you actually want to reproduce the whole object if it matches (if I understand correctly)
- you don't get any memory benefits from individually processing only parts of the input objects (this is often the reason for using `truncate_stream`) because in the end you still have to reconstruct the whole object in memory in order to produce it as output (again, if I understand correctly that whole objects is your expected output)

Comment: The OP is using `--stream` so that the filter can begin producing output as soon as it has read a single object from the stream; doesn't this need to read the entire input before beginning output? (Or is `--stream` only necessary if you want to start filtering, e.g, a very large single array?)

Comment: As presented in the question, the input is already a stream of objects, not an array which would have to be read in its entirety first. A stream of single objects can be processed immediately. (One could add the `--unbuffered` flag, but afaik single items in a stream are flushed outomatically.)

Comment: Ok, it's the path/leaf representation that confuses me, but yes, it is still a stream of  arrays representing any arbitrary JSON object.

Comment: The input is a stream of JSON objects in a (growing and rotating) file. I was underestimating jq (always a risk :) and the stream can really be processed immediately. Thanks!